Filtering files in PyPDFDirectoryLoader
I would like to limit the files loaded using langchain_community.document_loaders.pdf.PyPDFDirectoryLoader to a specific list. I tried using glob but there is some odd behaviour there
For instance, say I have
files_to_load = ["a.pdf", "b.pdf", "c.pdf"]

This does not work (loads 0 files)
loader = PyPDFDirectoryLoader("docs/", glob = "|".join(files_to_load))

This does not work either
loader = PyPDFDirectoryLoader("docs/", glob = "["+"|".join(files_to_load)+"]")

however running glob.glob with the same string does return the right files
Am I missing something obvious?

Not sure how that's working for you with glob.glob. Neither glob nor fnmatch use the usual re rules for pattern matching, but the Unix shell rules. On top of that, PyPDFDirectoryLoader is using pathlib.Path.glob for it's expansion (uses slightly expanded fnmatch-style rules). I don't believe there's an easy way to do what you want (yes for your example names, with one-letter stems, but not for longer names)

This seems to be working.
filter = ("["+("|".join(files_to_load))+"]*")
# remove .pdf <- this is key, otherwise it does not work
filter = filter.replace('.pdf', '')
loader = PyPDFDirectoryLoader(data_path, glob=filter)
documents = loader.load()

I am still a bit unsure of why it does work but...
